# Как добиться того, чтобы внутри кнопки не переносился текст на новую строчку?

Tags: css

[image: flex-wrap: wrap]

[image: flex-wrap: nowrap]

Мне надо добиться того, чтобы внутри кнопки текст не переносился на вторую строчку, был в одну, расширяя кнопку. Это происходит автоматически, если задать свойство flex-wrap: wrap, как на первом скриншоте, но проблема в том, что мне нужна одна прокручивающаяся строка, как на втором скриншоте. Но тогда внутри кнопок переносятся строчки и они раздуваются в высоту. Я пробовал ограничивать высоту кнопок, пробовал задавать свойство ширине fit-content, но этого не сработало. Подскажите, как добиться того, чтобы кнопки были как на первом скриншоте, но при этом располагались в одну строчку, как на втором?

Comment: Можно использовать тэг <nobr>. Но при этом вам нужно будет следить за тем чтобы ширина одной кнопки не превысила ширину страницы.

Comment: Добавить кнопкам `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: Оба ответа выше решают проблему, спасибо.